org-mode passing parameters to code snippets
Suppose, we have a source block that looks like this:
#+NAME: result_test
#+BEGIN_SRC perl :noweb yes :tangle yes
$test_name = "\$result is an array ref";
unless (is(ref $result, 'ARRAY', $test_name)) {
    die __LINE__;
}
$test_num++;
#+END_SRC

This code checks whether a variable $result has type of an array ref in Perl.
The macro is used like this:
#+NAME: code
#+BEGIN_SRC perl :noweb yes :tangle yes
my $result = my_function();
<<result_test>>
#+END_SRC

But now I need to check whether $result is a hash reference. So the code should look like this:
$test_name = "\$result is an array ref";
unless (is(ref $result, 'HASH', $test_name)) {
    die __LINE__;
}
$test_num++;

Is it possible to pass parameters to macros, so it generated different code blocks depending upon parameter passed?
Something like this:
<<result_test 'ARRAY'>>
<<result_test 'HASH'>>


It is not possible.

BTW, macro means something else in Org mode: see Macro Replacement
